# Can't change the email settings on google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

[i keep getting this email when i don't have any scripts on my account anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cleXA.png)

[Link 1 Click here: brings me to the forbidden site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJYu2.png)

How do i get rid of this??

Comment: Please include enough detail in the question for it to be understandable/answerable even if the links fail.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to script.google.com
2) In the menu Select Resources -> All your triggers
3) Find the markToGeneratereport trigger.
4) Click the X to the left of the trigger.